# Offset window top to account for fixed header when clicking an href that links to a div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This ones really been bugging me, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have a footer with a taxonomy of the site in it. It lists links to each page, as well as sections(divs) on that page. Each div has an id, so my href reads like this sitename.com/pagename#divid.

When clicked, the corresponding page loads to the correct section. However, it aligns the top of that div to the top of the window, which is unfortunately, covered by an 80px fixed header.

I need to js to recognize that div id has been clicked and load the corresponding page with an 80px offset of windowtop. I have tried many things found on other stackoverflow posts but nothing works.

This is what I've currently put together which I feel like is on the right track. However, its not working.

Can anyone help?

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 var headHeight = $('.main-header').height();
 if(window.location.hash) {
  $(body).scrollTop() - headHeight;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(body).scrollTop() - headHeight;
```

The above statement will not effectively do anything. (the statement is calculating the desired scrollTop target but you're not using the evaluated result)

Try instead:

```
$(body).scrollTop($(body).scrollTop() - headHeight);
```